# spectrum for a baseband communication signal

Tags: digital-communications

I have a question for the spectrum:
In baseband before passing through channel, should the spectrum of a communication signal be symmetrical?

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you are dealing with real signals, be it in baseband or passband, the magnitude spectrum is symmetrical around $f=0$.

For mathematical convenience, quadrature signals are often written as complex. A baseband quadrature signal (also called the "complex envelope" or the "low-pass equivalent signal") is complex, and its magnitude spectrum is no longer expected to be symmetrical.